# Python find data in table row

Tags: python, html-tableextract

Lets say i have a html table with 10 columns and 100 rows all i want to do is to use Beautifulsoup to look up for a data if exits and print full row.

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSou
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asian_countries_by_area"
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print(tds)
```

Comment: it'd be nice if you provide the HTML structure in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
import urllib3
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def searchTableForCountry(country):
    outlist = []
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asian_countries_by_area"
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('tr'):
          if(len(td.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'/wiki/' + country)})) >=1):
                outlist.append(td.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\xa0',' '))
                print(''.join(outlist))
    return outlist

searchTableForCountry('China')
#2   China  9,596,961  excludes Hong Kong, Macau, Taiwan and disputed areas/islands
```

Comment: thankyou @Ian-Fogelman
i want to search for a country name if it exits then print the row for the that country.
appending it to a list ? please help

Comment: hello @Ian-Fogelman i have <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; text-align:left;">Dog</td>
how can i use soup to find like td.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'/wiki/' + country)})